# Confusion with updating params in react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using react navigation I am forwarding an array and a function to update the array as params to a new screen. The new screen successfully updates this array, but the changes aren't seen on that screen. The changes are only seen when you return to the previous screen. What is the reason for this behavior and is there a way to go around it?

Comment: Can you provide a sample?

Comment: You use ({route}) or (props)?

Comment: @LinhNguyễnNgọc route

Comment: You try to print route.params? Try <Text>{JSON.stringify(route.params)}</Text> to show array first. If it shown, you have to check your function.

Comment: @LinhNguyễnNgọc The array is updated, but in the params the array isn't updated when I print it.

Comment: So how you know array updated?